# "PlatformNotSupportedException: COM is not supported" Error when Parsing Excel Files in .NET 6 Docker Container

Tags: c#, docker, com

In my web application, I have a .NET 6 DLL that reads and parses Excel files. The DLL utilizes the following namespaces:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Range = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range;
```

Everything works flawlessly on my local machine. However, when I run the application within a Docker container, it functions well until I attempt to parse an Excel file. At that point, I encounter the following error message:

```
2023-08-31 09:36:35 fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.DefaultHubDispatcher[8]
2023-08-31 09:36:35       Failed to invoke hub method 'Execute'.
2023-08-31 09:36:35       System.PlatformNotSupportedException: COM is not supported
2023-08-31 09:36:35          at Lib.ExcelParser.standatt.DatatableFromFileCreator.GetExcelFile(String path) in /Lib.ExcelParser.standatt/DatatableFromFileCreator.cs:line 36
2023-08-31 09:36:35          at WebPrecCalc.ChatHub.GetTableFromFiles(String filePath1, String filePath2) in /WebPrecCalc/ChatHub.cs:line 240
2023-08-31 09:36:35          at WebPrecCalc.ChatHub.Execute(String user, String fileName1, String fileName2, Boolean isPatoor) in /WebPrecCalc/ChatHub.cs:line 119
2023-08-31 09:36:35          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.DefaultHubDispatcher`1.ExecuteMethod(ObjectMethodExecutor methodExecutor, Hub hub, Object[] arguments)
2023-08-31 09:36:35          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.DefaultHubDispatcher`1.<Invoke>g__ExecuteInvocation|16_0(DefaultHubDispatcher`1 dispatcher, ObjectMethodExecutor methodExecutor, THub hub, Object[] arguments, AsyncServiceScope scope, IHubActivator`1 hubActivator, HubConnectionContext connection, HubMethodInvocationMessage hubMethodInvocationMessage, Boolean isStreamCall)
```

The code that triggers the issue is as follows:

```
public System.Data.DataTable GetExcelFile(string path)
{
    Application xlApp = new Application();// failes here
    Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(path);
}
```

Is there a way to address this "COM is not supported" error when running my application in a Docker container? Any guidance or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: COM is a Windows technology, so won't work in a, what I assume is Linux-based, Docker container.

Comment: If @MartinCostello is correct and you think about switching to a Windows Container now also remember that you need to install Excel in that Container then so that Excel Interop can work. You presumably need a 3rd party product for excel file parsing to get rid of the Excel dependency and can run in a Linux environment.